# Can I Run a dotnet app which is hosted on IIS in a docker container?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, docker, docker-compose

I have developed a web application using asp dotnet and currently I have it running on IIS is there anyway I can run the same app in a docker container,

I am relatively new to Docker and I have played around a bit and I am familiar with docker compose , so I was wondering if I can (dockerize) the application that I have developed.

My Dockerfile now looks like:

```
#Making a dotnet container
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

#Make a directory
WORKDIR /app

#copy dll files and other dependencies
COPY . /app

#dotnet run should run the app
ENTRYPOINT ["DOTNET","RUN"]
```

From what I understand this makes a directory inside my dotnet container and copies the files in the current folder and the app will run on dotnet run

Comment: Microsoft has released their dotnet code as an image on hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/

Comment: I understand that we can run an app but can I run it on IIS? I want to ship this container around like a package with all the files and dependancies in it

Comment: I have a config file and dependencies for the app so I copied all these into a folder inside the container

I tried creating a dockerfile but the container refuses to run the app on a port in the background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change a little your Dockerfile, try this:

```
#Making a dotnet container
FROM microsoft/iis

SHELL ["powershell"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \  
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45

RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'  
RUN New-Website -Name 'app' -Port 80 \  
    -PhysicalPath 'c:\app' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'

#copy dll files and other dependencies
COPY app app

#dotnet run should run the app
CMD ["ping", "-t", "localhost"]
```

Test it

```
docker build -t app .  
docker run --name app -d -p 80:80 app
docker inspect --format="{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress}}" app
```

It will give you an ip just test it in your browser.

More information: [Run IIS + ASP.NET on Windows 10 with Docker](http://blog.alexellis.io/run-iis-asp-net-on-windows-10-with-docker/)

Comment: Thanks for the response.. apparently I have been trying to run IIS in Linux container which IIS does not support so there was an issue.

I have done it in windows 10 and seems to be working good. 

Thank you.

Comment: And now I have a new issue wherein I have been trying to access a mssql server of my organization from inside the container("the container with the app running") but the app does not seem to be able to access this server. It works fine when I try it with Visual Studio but when I run the app in a container I have connection issues.

Comment: I recommend you to open a new question about it